# ggplot2 continuous values for discrete scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.table formated like this (but bigger) and named data3 :

```
    V1 V2        V3        V4            V5
1    6  1  50000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
2    5  1  50000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
3    4  1  50000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
4    3  1  50000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
5    2  1  50000000 100000000  7.407407e-01
6    1  1  50000000 100000000  5.925926e+00
7   -1  1  50000000 100000000 -4.370370e+01
8   -2  1  50000000 100000000 -7.407407e-01
9    6  1 150000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
10   5  1 150000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
11   4  1 150000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
12   3  1 150000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
13   2  1 150000000 100000000  3.703704e+00
14   1  1 150000000 100000000  5.925926e+00
15  -1  1 150000000 100000000 -1.481481e+01
16  -2  1 150000000 100000000  0.000000e+00
```

I separated positive and negative values with :

```
subdat1=subset(data3, V1>0)
subdat2=subset(data3, V1<0)
```

I made an histogram using this code :

```
ggplot(data=data3) + 
  facet_grid(~V2, space="free_x", scales="free_x", labeller=label_value)+ 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="red", size=1) + 
  geom_bar(data=subdat1,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(data=subdat2,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="CNV"))
```

And I obtained something close to what I want :
[image]

But legend is not discrete (one color per value of V1) and is not in good order.
So I tryed this :

```
ggplot(data=data3)+ 
  facet_grid(~V2, space="free_x", scales="free_x", labeller=label_value)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="red", size=1) + 
  geom_bar(data=subdat1,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(data=subdat2,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity") + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="CNV"))+
  scale_colour_gradient(trans="identity")
```

but had the following error :

```
Erreur : Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

I thus tried this, to transform values and use discrete levels :

```
subdat1$V1 <- factor(subdat1$V1, levels = rev(levels(factor(subdat1$V1))))
subdat2$V1 <- factor(subdat2$V1, levels = levels(factor(subdat2$V1)))
```

and tried again the ggplot but I had this error now :

```
Erreur dans unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

And I have no more idea....
Help would be greatly appreciated !

EDIT :
I just tried again with :

```
ggplot(data=data3)+  
  facet_grid(~V2, space="free_x", scales="free_x", labeller=label_value)+  
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank())+  
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="red", size=1)+   
  geom_bar(data=subdat1,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity")+ 
  geom_bar(data=subdat2,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity")+   
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="CNV"))
```

and succeed to obtain :

[image]

So, I am getting closer.
How could I just inverse not only the legend, but also the order in the upper histogram ?

Comment: `fill=factor(V1)` doesn't help?

Comment: No, but i could improve removing scale_colour_gradient(trans="identity"),  see my EDIT

Comment: you can change the legend order manually with  `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -2, -1))`. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/#changing-the-order-of-items-in-the-legend

Comment: Yes it works ! Thanks. But I would also like to change the order in the upper histograms because 1 values are at the top and not at the bottom. I don't know if I am clear...

Comment: Please use linebreaks (after the `+` symbols) in your ggplot2 code. It's difficult to read as it is.

Comment: Sorry, double space do not work...

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did :

```
ggplot(data=data3)+ facet_grid(~V2, space="free_x", scales="free_x", labeller=label_value)+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank()) +geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="red", size=1) + geom_bar(data=subdat1,aes(x=V3, y=rev(V5), fill=rev(V1), width=V4), stat="identity")+geom_bar(data=subdat2,aes(x=V3, y=V5, fill=V1, width=V4), stat="identity") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="CNV")) +scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1, -2))
```

I use rev() function in y and fill. But.... Data are like stretched.... ?

[image]

Any Idea ??

Comment: That seems to be completely different barplot. As @Roland suggested, using linebreaks after +s is a good practice. More readable, and easier to spot errors. If you wanna change the order of stacked bars in the upper part you might want to add `order=rev(V1)` to `aes`thetics.

Comment: Yes, I think data from V1 with rev() have been reversed from right to left in reality, that's why it's seems another one. So rev() is not the solution. What I finally did, is that I directly change the format of the input file and it works !